# how to add ec2-user to hadoop in aws emr

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, emr, amazon-emr

I'm newbie in aws emr and want to add new user and creating some directory in hadoop.

so what I'm doing for create directory.

login in hadoop machine

```
ssh hadoop@(publicIP)
hadoop fs -mkdir /user
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/tomcat/
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tomcat
```

I want to do this process using aws-cli or adding this approach to EMR-bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your make-directory commands in a shell script, and add that script as a step. You can do this while launching your cluster:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "Test cluster" --ami-version 3.10 --applications Name=Hue Name=Hive Name=Pig \
--use-default-roles --ec2-attributes KeyName=myKey \
--instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 3 \
--steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name=CustomJAR,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Jar=s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,Args=["s3://mybucket/script-path/my_script.sh"]
```

or add this as FIRST step in the job flow after launching your cluster:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id <<$clusterId>> --steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name=CustomJAR,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Jar=s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,Args=["s3://mybucket/script-path/my_script.sh"
```